# Respond to buttons click in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, recyclerview-layout

I have a `RecyclerView` where the user has to click the elements to cast a vote to that specific player.

---

## Current Layout

[image: Current Layout]

---

As it's not that much intuitive, I'd like to add `Button`s on the right side of each element to let the user understand that he needs to click if he wants to cast a vote.

---

### Question

How do I make a custom `layout` like that? Probably using a `GridLayout`? And mostly, how do I get the `Button`'s `element`'s `position` when the button (and it only) gets clicked?

---

### Code

- list_players.xml | http://pastebin.com/F7Ei07x9
- two_line_list_item_horizontal.xml | http://pastebin.com/s8qvwqt4
- CourseAdapter.java | http://pastebin.com/qZJeimfe

Comment: post your code please

Comment: check this tutorial for example http://wiki.workassis.com/android-recyclerview-example/

Answer (score 0):

You can use **LinearLayout** to add button to your **Recyclerview** item by giving them **weight**.

You can handle **onClicklistener** of that button in ViewHolder class and you can get position of clicked button by **getAdapterPosition()** in **ViewHolder** class.

As per your request :

XML :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="5">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:text="ABCD"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:text="A"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Vote"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Adapter :

```
public class Holder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        Button  btnVote;
        public Holder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            btnVote = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_vote);

            btnVote.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    //list.get(getAdapterPosition()); Use for get the data on selected item
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: May I ask you to leave me a brief snippet I can read and understand? Posted some code if you may need to have a look!

Comment: The list is my RecyclerView?

Comment: @FET is it useful for you ?

Comment: I think, fact is I get all the data from a provider. To get such data I need to get this provider first. As I have all fragments, I usually do this: `private DataProvider provider = (DataProvider) getActivity();`. But this adapter class doesn't extend either fragment or activity, so I don't know how to get it and so get the data list

Comment: @FET The adapter can't extend an Activity or a Fragment ! But you can have a reference inside the adapter to the right context.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti So what should I do in order to get the provider and finally the needed data?

Answer (score 0):

Replace your CoursesAdapter's onBindViewHolder with this.

```
 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(CoursesViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Player player = mArrayCourses.get(position);
        holder.name.setText(player.getName());
        holder.counter.setText(String.valueOf(player.getCount()));
        holder.voteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Do your work here
            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: How do I get the position of the element clicked?

Comment: public void onBindViewHolder(CoursesViewHolder holder, int position)

here position is your current item position

Comment: Fact is I get all the data from a provider. To get such data I need to get this provider first. As I have all fragments, I usually do this: private DataProvider provider = (DataProvider) getActivity();. But this adapter class doesn't extend either fragment or activity, so I don't know how to get the data I need from it in this class

Comment: you can pass the context of your activity or fragment to the constructor of your adapter class and use it.